# Why JBoss does not allow to use multiple endorsed directories?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

> The system property **java.endorsed.dirs** specifies one **or more directories** that the Java runtime environment will search for such JAR files.

Why does JBoss allow to use only one endorsed directory?
There is following code in jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.bat:

```
set JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% ^
   -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%" ^
   -classpath "%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%" ^
   org.jboss.Main %*
```

I need to put one jar to endorsed directory.
But I cannot put it to **%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed** directory because on production environments this directory is readonly.
But I can change startup parameters of JBoss.
So I decided to add one more endorsed directory via startup parameters.
But I cannot do it because JBoss uses only its own **java.endorsed.dirs="%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%"**.

Comment: What do you mean? Please look how run.bat starts JBoss. It adds its own -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%".

Comment: just alter the bat file. We have our own starting scripts for jboss (adding some option, boot path, so on)